# How to view the source code of numpy.random.exponential?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to see if `numpy.random.exponential` was implemented using F^{-1} (U) method, where F is the c.d.f of exponential distribution and U is uniform distribution.

I tried `numpy.source(random.exponential)`, but returned '*Not available for this object'*. Does it mean this function is not written in Python?

I also tried `inspect.getsource(random.exponential)`, but returned an error saying it's not module, function, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

numpy's sources are [at github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) so you can use github's [source-search](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=exponential).

As often, these parts of the library are not implemented in pure python.

The python-parts (in regards to your question) are [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7ccf0e08917d27bc0eba34013c1822b00a66ca6d/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx):

The more relevant code-part is from [distributions.c](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c):

```
double rk_standard_exponential(rk_state *state)
{
    /* We use -log(1-U) since U is [0, 1) */
    return -log(1.0 - rk_double(state));
}

double rk_exponential(rk_state *state, double scale)
{
    return scale * rk_standard_exponential(state);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A lot of numpy functions are written with C/C++ and Fortran. `numpy.source()` returns the source code only for objects written in Python. It is written on [NumPy website](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.source.html).

You can find all of the NumPy functions on their GitHub page. One that you need is written in C. Here is the link to the [file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/distributions.c).